# can I use SchedulingRule to replace synchronzation

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, concurrency

Can I change my code from:

```
class Sample{
    private Object _lock=new Object();
    public void someMethod(){
        synchronized(_lock){
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
class Sample{
    private ISchedulingRule _lock=new SomeSchedulingRule();
    public void someMethod(){
        try{
            Job.getManager().beginRule(_lock);
            doSomething();
        }finally{
            Job.getManager().endRule(_lock);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm reading "java concurrency in practice", and they say if I wanna use some explicit lock, I have to guarantee the memory visibility.

So the question is:

**If I can guarantee the memory visibility, can I use the code at bottom to replace the code at top(replace intrinsic synchronization with eclipse IJobManager.beginRule and IJobManager.endRule)**

Comment: Why do you want to use the code at the bottom instead of the one at the top?

Comment: @Tudor: He's interested in whether using explicit lock objects guarantees memory visibility. It's a general question.

Comment: @Alex D: And what is this "explicit lock" you speak of?

Comment: @Tudor: ISchedulingRule has two methods which are both very very powerful.
It will be amazing if I can use it as an explicit lock

Comment: @Tudor: Look at the API docs for `java.util.concurrent`. There's a number of explicit lock classes in there.

Comment: @Alex D: Ah ok, I know about those. So locks on which you manually call lock-unlock are called explicit?

Comment: @Tudor. Yes. When you use a `synchronized` block or method, you don't have to explicitly say "I'm locking here" and "I'm unlocking here". With lock objects you do.

Comment: @Temple Wing: Are you using the latest API? Because I looked around for the source code and the methods have different names than what you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to achieve synchronization then the answer is yes.

That said, there are some (hidden) gotchas that you need to be aware of. Since `JobManager` is designed to prevent dead-locks to some extent, then there are somewhat strict rules for using and defining nested rules (a limitation that Java synchronized blocks don't have). There is no public API for checking whether a thread is holding a rule/lock or not. Also, `beginRule` cannot be canceled by calling interrupt on waiting thread. To name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source code I found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse.core/jobs/3.4.100/org/eclipse/core/internal/jobs/JobManager.java#JobManager.beginRule%28org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ISchedulingRule%2Corg.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor%29) is up to date, you can check that the `beginRule` method calls `implicitJob.begin` which has a large `synchronized(this)` block inside.

Comment: It's 3.50. The latest version of eclipse is 4.2 Juno.

Comment: I think I'm wrong. It shouldn't depends on whether it is implemented using synchronization.

Comment: @Temple Wing: `synchronized` blocks introduce implicit memory fences, which give you memory visibility. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a web tutorial on concurrency which makes the following statement:

> Well, it turns out that a contract of the Lock interface is that it provides the same >memory barrier behaviour as synchronized.

That's referring to the "Lock" interface in `java.util.concurrent`. I don't know whether it applies to the `ISchedulingRule` interface which you show here.

Comment: The `beginRule` method actually uses `synchronized` inside.

Comment: That answers the OP's question -- you should post it as a separate answer.